# Activate iOS Email app when E-Mail address in a TextField is tapped

Tags: ios, email, textfield

I am writing a contact app and am having problems figuring out how to activate the e-mail app on my iPhone/iPad from within my app.  I can add in the e-mail address into the textfield but i haven't figured out when I tap on it how to get that address into the e-mail app on the device.  All I can find for tutorial is on E-Mails with a specific e-mail address already coded into the app.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
NSLog(@"Setting the value of fields in this static table to that of the passed Person");
//self.personNameTextField.text = self.person.name;
self.personFirstnameTextField.text = self.person.firstname;
self.personSurnameTextField.text = self.person.surname;
self.personEmailTextField.text = self.person.email;

self.personEventTableViewCell.textLabel.text = self.person.inEvent.name;
self.selectedEvent = self.person.inEvent; // ensure null role doesn't get saved.
    [super viewDidLoad];

_personFirstnameTextField.delegate = self;
_personSurnameTextField.delegate = self;
_personEmailTextField.delegate = self;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@",         _personEmailTextField.text]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove url code from viewDidLoad.

In Textfield delegate..

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

 if (textField == _personEmailTextField) {

     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@", _personEmailTextField.text]];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];

   }

}
```

No need to use MFMailComposer if u simply want to open Compose window/Mail app.

Answer (score 0):

You want the [`MFMailComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) this will open a mail composer in your app. It will use the users account from the iOS mail app.